# What is the most efficient way for me to get Hadoop running on a private OpenStack Cloud

Tags: hadoop, openstack

I want to use Hadoop on OpenStack to do workload characterization. However, I'm not sure how to get Hadoop running on the OpenStack cloud that I have access to. What is the most efficient way for me to get Hadoop running on a private OpenStack Cloud?

I've seen this:

http://hortonworks.com/blog/running-hadoop-openstack-with-hortonworks-sandbox/

I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into OpenStack Savanna project.   
 
https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Savanna